# Question About FDM and Boundary Conditions

Tags: matrices, finite-differences, boundary-value-problem

I'm taking a numerical analysis class and have a quick question about boundary conditions. I don't understand how boundary conditions are incorporated into the matrix form of the FDM.

Can someone please explain how each boundary condition would be incorporated into the matrix, such as in this example?

http://people.nas.nasa.gov/~pulliam/Classes/New_notes/Matrix_ODE.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: As a 1-dimensional transient problem it has one initial condition (IC) and one boundary condition (BC). Page 5 of the example you gave should provide you a hint. For each time step you must solve a $[A]\overline{u} = -\overline{bc}$ system. Thus your BC is incorporated into $\overline{bc}_1$, with a changed sign because it is $-\overline{bc}$. Observe that since $\overline{bc}$ is a column vector, the "**_T_**" in $\overline{bc}=[-\frac{a}{2\Delta x}u_{left},...]^T$ indicates its transposed (for editoral purposes, it is better to express a column vector as the transposed of a row vector).